# Cinema Display Screen Blemish

Tags: display, hardware, cinema-display

I have an oldish Apple Cinema Display (23" DVI) that I haven't used in a while and that I want to connect to my Mac. When I connected it, I discovered this weird whitish tarnish.
[image: not pretty]
[image: not pretty either]

How could this have happened and, more importantly, is there a way to DIY repair it?

Comment: If that is a 'pixel artefact' -- i.e. not there when switched off, then I think the display has had it. If it's 'physical', then I suppose it might be condensation (or mould?) between the layers, in which case you'd have to take it apart.

Comment: Did you store it in a damp area? Did you or someone spill stuff on it?

Comment: I'm not sure if it was in a damp area, but could've been. Haven't spilled anything onto the monitor. You can't see the whitish haze when the monitor is switched off.

Comment: It is so odd that there is such a pronounced [pin cushion pattern](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distortion_(optics)) on a flat display.  Was anything pressed up against it?  Is the display panel still smooth or is there a “texture”?

Comment: Panel is smooth. Nothing was pressed up against it. The display's been standing there on its own for a few years.

Comment: What about the environment?  Is it in a very humid location?   I have to keep desiccant  packs in my camera gear to prevent mold from forming on my lenses.

Comment: No, it's not a humid environment at all.

Answer (score -1):

> How could this have happened?

#### [Delamination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delamination)

Based on the images you provided, it appears that the whitish tarnish on your display could be due to a process called "**delamination**". It basically occurs when the layers of a display panel separate or develop air gaps, resulting in a cloudy or hazy appearance. It is a common issue with older displays (such as yours) and can affect image quality as you may have already noticed.

---

> Is there a way to DIY repair it?

Unfortunately, delamination is not something that can be easily *repaired*<sup>1</sup> through DIY methods. It typically requires professional intervention or replacement of the display panel. I recommend contacting Apple support or an Apple Store for help even though this is an old display and they might not have the corresponding parts.

<sup><sup>1</sup>Note that it cannot be easily *repaired*. Of course, you could replace your display using DIY methods but repairing it when it's been through delamination is way harder.</sup>